# Where is font WenQuanYi Bitmap Song?

Tags: debian, fonts, debian-installer

I have installed xfonts-wqy in my newly installed Debian Jessie stable, by using the following command

```
 # aptitude search xfonts-wqy
 i  xfonts-wqy - WenQuanYi Bitmap Song CJK font for X
```

As you can see, the letter "i" before "xfonts-wqy - Wen..." tells us that the installation of xfonts-wqy is successful.

But when I list the font, there is nothing about WenQuanYi Bitmap Song, as you can see here:

```
[04/29/2015,10:49:53@~]$ fc-list |grep WenQuanYi
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy/wqy-microhei.ttc: WenQuanYi Micro Hei,文泉驛微米黑,文泉驿微米黑:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy/wqy-zenhei.ttc: WenQuanYi Zen Hei,文泉驛正黑,文泉驿正黑:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy/wqy-zenhei.ttc: WenQuanYi Zen Hei Sharp,文泉驛點陣正黑,文泉驿点阵正黑:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy/wqy-zenhei.ttc: WenQuanYi Zen Hei Mono,文泉驛等寬正黑,文泉驿等宽正黑:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy/wqy-microhei.ttc: WenQuanYi Micro Hei Mono,文泉驛等寬微米黑,文泉驿等宽微米黑:style=Regular
```

So, my question is: **Where is the font WenQuanYi Bitmap Song? And how can I use this font?**

I also tried to reinstall xfonts-wqy several times, but the problem is still there.

Here is some information about my Debian Jessie:

```
[04/29/2015,10:46:36@~]$ uname -a
Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt9-3~deb8u1 (2015-04-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
[04/29/2015,10:54:06@~]$ mate-about -v
MATE Desktop Environment 1.8.1
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This won't help, but when I do the same on Debian 7.8, it works as expected. fc-list shows the .pcf fonts. So it's not you; maybe it's your system. Is there any setting that displays only outline fonts (i.e. ignoring bitmapped ones)?

Comment: Actually before I upgrade to Debian Jessie, that is in Debian 7.8, all things went right. I could use WenQuanYi Bitmap Song. But when I upgrade to Debian several days ago, the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The fonts are installed into `/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc` with filenames like `wenquanyi_13px.pcf`, but the question still remains as to why `fc-list` didn't find them there.  When you installed `xfonts-wqy`, one of the things it *should* have said was `Regenerating fonts cache... done`. You can do this manually with more verbosity via the command `fc-cache -vf` and watch its output to see which directories it is checking.  If it doesn't check `X11`, look into your [fonts-conf files](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html) to make sure they haven't been changed (by you or a script) to make the directory search more specific---there *should* be something like `<dir>/usr/share/fonts</dir>` in one of the fonts-conf files (probably `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`); if it only says `/usr/share/fonts/truetype` then that's the problem; in the worst case you might have to reset your `fontconfig-config` package and everything that depends on it.